# convert htaccess to nginx

Tags: htaccess, nginx

I want to convert this htaccess code to nginx.

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>    
RewriteEngine On
## Application Handler   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d    
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)?$ index.php?a=$1  [QSA,NC,L]    
## Error 404 ##
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?a=404    
</ifModule>"
```

I use winginx to convert when I inserted the code into nginx, there is a problem downloading the file. Can anyone help me? thank you

Answer (score 2):

The two `RewriteCond` statements perform the same function as the Nginx `try_files` directive. For example:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?a=$uri;
```

However, the `RewriteRule` probably appends the original request without the leading `/`, so a more accurate translation might be:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?a=$1;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

---

The error handler is translated to either of (depending on what status code you need):

```
error_page 404 /index.php?a=404;
error_page 404 = /index.php?a=404;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page) for details.

Comment: thank bro.I did it